# Why is ( Infinity | 0 ) === 0?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, infinity, bitwise-or

I'm fiddling around with bitwise operators in JavaScript and there is one thing I find remarkable.

The [bitwise or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29) returns `1` as output bit if one of the two input bits are `1`. So doing `x | 0` always returns `x`, because `| 0` has no effect:

- `( 1 | 0 ) === 1`
- `( 0 | 0 ) === 0`

However, when I calculated `Infinity | 0`, I got `0`. This is surprising in my opinion, because by the above one should get `Infinity`. After all, `( x | 0 ) === x`.

I cannot find where in the ECMAscript specification this is explicitly defined, so I was wondering what exactly implies that `( Infinity | 0 ) === 0`. Is is perhaps the way `Infinity` is stored in memory? If so, how can it still be that doing a `| 0` operation causes it to return `0` whereas `| 0` should not do anything?

Comment: How could you compute `(infinity | 0)`? Infinity is... infinite, it can't be computed by its very definition... :|

Comment: @Albireo - Because a computer has to represent infinity somehow, and it's got a limited number of bits to do it with.

Comment: This is really interesting, because `Infinity` appears to be a truthy value when you use it in an if-else statement, like one would expect. I just confirmed this: http://jsfiddle.net/LWBVd/. Perhaps it has to do with the internal representation of `Infinity`.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: Looking at the answers it appears that values are converted to an integer first. Just like `0.1` is truthy, `0.1 | 0` is falsy.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Bitwise operators work on integers only.
`Infinity` is a floating-point value, not an integer.

The spec [says](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.10) that all operands of bitwise operations are converted to integers (using the *ToInt32* operation) before performing the operation.

The [*ToInt32* operation](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_9.5) says:

> If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞ or –∞ return +0.

Answer (score 2):

Doing math and other operations that expect integers with `NaN` and `Infinity` is usually a bad idea. How would you set/clear a bit from *Infinity*?

Actually, bit-wise operations are only defined for integers - and integers do not have `NaN` or `Infinity`.

Comment: I was thinking that `Infinity` would represent an infinite amount of `1` bits after each other.

Comment: That's more like -1 than infinity (in that this is how -1 behaves in languages like python that have arbitrary size integers - javascript only has 32 bit integers.)

Comment: @Random832: I guess I was thinking too simplistically. My idea was that just like `1` is `1` and `1111` is `16`, `111...111` would end up to Infinity.

Comment: 1111 binary is 15.  If you follow this line of reasoning an infinite value would occupy every bit in memory and would still not accurately portray infinity.

Comment: @dbasnett: It's 15 indeed, my stupidity. I was thinking it would *represent* an infinite amount of ones so that `Infinity | 0 === 111...111 | 0 === 111...111 === Infinity`. But never mind, it's not the case :)